# Modify default separators in json.dump in python 2.7.1

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

In a json.dump method (python 2.7.1) the output has the default separator as (',' and ': '). I want to remove the comma and the colon so that my outputs are simply separated by white space.

I also want to remove the opening and closing braces. Is there any particular attribute of *separator* or string formatting that allows me to do this or is there any other solution?

For example after applying

with open(foutput, 'a') as f1:
    json.dump(newdict, f1,sort_keys=True,indent=4)

I am getting output as :

```
{
    "0.671962000": 51.61292129099999, 
    "0.696699155": 51.61242420999999, 
    "0.721436310": 51.610724798999996, 
    "0.746173465": 51.60536924799999, 
    "0.770910620": 51.58964636499999, 
    "0.795647775": 51.543248571999996, 
    "0.820384930": 51.381941735, 
}
```

But I want the below type output instead of that:

```
0.671962000  -28.875564044
0.696699155  -28.876061125
0.721436310  -28.877760536
0.746173465  -28.883116087
0.770910620  -28.898838970
```

Please note I only want this in python.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's not JSON. You are producing CSV data, why not use the `csv` module instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not producing JSON, so **don't use the JSON module**. You are producing CSV data, with a space as delimiter. Use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), or use simple string formatting.

Using the `csv` module:

```
import csv

with open(foutput, 'a', newline='') as f1:
    writer = csv.writer(f1, delimiter=' ')
    writer.writerows(sorted(newdict.items()))
```

or simply using string formatting:

```
with open(foutput, 'a') as f1:
    for key, value in sorted(newdict.items()):
        f1.write('{} {}\n'.format(key, value)
```

Comment: newline=''  was getting an error stating TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function ; After removing the newline it worked properly. Thank you.

Comment: @SamudranilRoy: I wrote the answer with the assumption you use Python 3. For Python 2, use `'ab'` as the mode for the `csv` module. The CSV standard is specific about how line endings are used, and those options allow the module to control them tightly.

Comment: @SamudranilRoy: any reason you removed the 'accept' mark, anything missing you feel I should add?

Comment: It was by mistake may be.. I have not done intensionally. Sorry for  the inconvenience.